# Function to search in two tables in SQL Server 2012

Tags: function, sql-server-2012

I need to create a function that returns a column, but this column has to be searched for in two different tables depending on a parameter.

If the parameter has the value "F", the function will look in the table "A", otherwise the column will be searched in table "B".

Is it possible to do this?

I tried to create the function in different ways but I did not get it to work properly.

Thank you very much

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getAlm] 
    (@doc nvarchar(20), @type nvarchar(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
        IF (@type = 'F')
        (
            SELECT [Center] 
            FROM [BDX].[dbo].[TABLE_A]
            WHERE [No_] = @doc
        )
        ELSE
        (
            SELECT [Center] 
            FROM [BDX].[dbo].[TABLE_B]
            WHERE [No_] = @doc
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a function you cannot use dynamically created statements and you can not use a variable as a table's name. But you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
DECLARE @SourceTable VARCHAR(100)='Table_A';

SELECT [Center] 
FROM [BDX].[dbo].[TABLE_A]
WHERE @SourceTable='Table_A'  
  AND [No_] = @doc

UNION ALL

SELECT [Center] 
FROM [BDX].[dbo].[TABLE_B]
WHERE @SourceTable='Table_B'  
  AND [No_] = @doc
```

This is for your situation

```
SELECT [Center] 
FROM [BDX].[dbo].[TABLE_A]
WHERE @type='F'  
  AND [No_] = @doc

UNION ALL

SELECT [Center] 
FROM [BDX].[dbo].[TABLE_B]
WHERE @type<>'F'  
  AND [No_] = @doc
```

Comment: Hello Shnugo!

Thank you very much for your answer. Your solution works perfectly.
Thanks again.